# I want to convert jdbc statement's result to json to be able to see in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my code

when i go to the url in postman, I should see what's in my text field of about_us table..

```
@RequestMapping("/about_us")
@GetMapping 
public void about_us() {    
    String x;
    jdbc.execute("select text from about_us");              
}
```

Comment: Please give more information; What have you tried? What did / didn't work? Etc.

Comment: Your code contains so many issues in these 5 lines that you should probably do some more research prior asking for a working solution. You will benefit more from it that way.

Answer (score 0):

**As I understanding you wants to get or send request data in JSON form, with the help of following annotation we can do.**

@RequestBody

```
Spring automatically deserializes the JSON into a Java type assuming an appropriate one is specified. By default, the type we annotate with the @RequestBody annotation must correspond to the JSON sent from our client-side controller
```

@ResponseBody

```
The @ResponseBody annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Controller doesn't response anything.
2. @GetMapping is alias of @RequestMapping(method=GET). Use just @GetMapping or @RequestMapping
3. If you want json reponse, use @RestController or @Controller + @ResponseBody

For example

```
@RestController
public class YourController {
    @GetMapping("/about_us")
    public String aboutUs() {
        String x;
        String text = jdbc.execute("select text from about_us");
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: it says cannot convert from void to string.

Comment: `jdbc.execute(...)`  is just a example. It does not return real result, it returns result statement. It's not the problem of spring. Java Jdbc programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using JDBC with RowMapper, my class as per below:

```
    @GetMapping("/testi2")
    public List<CustomerResponse> getCCP2() {
        String sql = "you query here";
        List<CustomerResponse> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
                sql,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(CustomerResponse.class));

        return result;
    }
}
```

For more research, you can check the below link:

[JdbcTemplate samples](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/)